# Issue with Button Images in ttk/Python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5, imagebutton, ttk

I'm messing around with ttk/tkinter in Python (3.5), and I'm having some issues with buttons (specifically, ttk.Button).

No matter what I try, I cannot for the life of me get an image to show up on a button.

I have the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Example(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        master.title('Button Test')

        self.configure(padding='10 10 10 10')
        self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, E, W, S))

        buttonImage = Image.open('play.png')
        buttonPhoto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(buttonImage)

        myButton = ttk.Button(self, image=buttonPhoto, padding='10 10 10 10')
        myButton.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(E, W))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    example = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

This is an amalgamation of examples I found [here](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/216852/an-image-button-python-and-tk), [here](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/fonts.html#images), and from users here on StackOverflow.

Thanks in advance for any ideas/insight.

-Sean

Comment: `PhotoImage` has problem with `garbage collector` which removes image if it is assigned to local variable. Assign image to class variable `self.buttonPhoto`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`PhotoImage` has problem with `garbage collector` which removes image if it is assigned to local variable.

Assign image to class variable `self.buttonPhoto`

```
self.buttonPhoto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(buttonImage)
```

Full:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Example(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        master.title('Button Test')

        self.configure(padding='10 10 10 10')
        self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, E, W, S))

        buttonImage = Image.open('play.png')

        # use self.buttonPhoto
        self.buttonPhoto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(buttonImage) 

        # use self.buttonPhoto
        myButton = ttk.Button(self, image=self.buttonPhoto, padding='10 10 10 10')
        myButton.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(E, W))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    example = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Or assign image to other object - it should stop `garbage collector` too.

ie.

```
    myButton.image = buttonPhoto
```

Full:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Example(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        master.title('Button Test')

        self.configure(padding='10 10 10 10')
        self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, E, W, S))

        buttonImage = Image.open('tplay.png')
        buttonPhoto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(buttonImage)

        myButton = ttk.Button(self, image=buttonPhoto, padding='10 10 10 10')
        myButton.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(E, W))
        # assign image to other object
        myButton.image = buttonPhoto

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    example = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

---

See `Note` at the end of page [The Tkinter PhotoImage Class](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Comment: That did it.  Very good information to have, and also explains part of one of the examples I cited.  Thanks, furas.

Comment: This works but I have a question. I Googled many references but didn't find option padding for ttk.Button. Why does it work here? Could you explain a bit more? Thanks.